# When do we need to clairify terms?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, voting

I've received 3 negative votes on this question, and no comments that aren't nonsense

[Can missing times concretely exist?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/69241/can-missing-times-concretely-exist)

Am I meant to define every term I use which anyone at all could struggle with, even when I link to a short [encyclopedia] article that clarifies them to any intelligent person's need?

Comment: i'm leaving and not coming back. i have provided a LOT of content for this site, and am not so arrogant that i think everything i say is relevant [to anyone but myself]./ good luck with your game

Comment: complete meltdown haha. forget it, this is not the format for difficult philosophical questions

Comment: It's an interesting topic but had I read it earlier I would have struggled to grasp quite what you're asking. Seems to me a bit of editing would sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

We should all be ready to clarify our questions at all times. You can preempt clarification requests by writing it as clearly as you can and including links to resources that explain more. Compound nouns in particular should be given definitions or links because they very often have meanings that are not just the sum of their parts.

But if you just call anyone else's comments nonsense then they won't be likely to be inclined to help you.

Comment: that's fair enough, but you don't **seem** to be aware that -ve votes can actually hinder the site -- let alone getting a question answered

Comment: @another_name No, I know they can be very discouraging to receive, but I didn't think votes were what you were asking about here so I didn't think they needed to be be mentioned.

Comment: i don't just mean discouraging, i mean they are worse for the site than "bad questions" which can be deleted easily

Comment: no reply to that then?

Comment: @another_name You've given your opinion, I've given mine, I don't see what more should be said.